# Mysql - Returning number of rows where JSON document is contained within a target JSON document

Tags: mysql, json

I have table with json column `data` in mysql.
In data column i am expecting to have some array of products for key "products".
I am analyzing the best and fastest approach to get number of rows containing specified value in array of products.

This is what i have tried so far, on 1 million of rows with given results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "cnt" FROM `components` `c`
WHERE (JSON_CONTAINS(`c`.`data`, '"some product from array"', '$."products"') = true)
```

first one takes ~4 sec

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "cnt" FROM `components` `c`
WHERE (JSON_SEARCH(`c`.`data`, 'one', 'some product from array', null, '$."products"') is not null)
```

second one takes ~2,5 sec

Is there any faster way i can get this number of rows?

I noticed that from Mysql 8.0.17 it is possible to add multi-valued indexes on a JSON column. Is it possible to create multi-valued index on array of strings. I tried something like:

```
CREATE INDEX products ON components ( (CAST(data->'$.products' AS VARCHAR(255) ARRAY)) )
```

but it gives me error. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Best regards.

Comment: Could be an indexing issue. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389075/how-to-create-index-on-json-column-in-mysql)

Comment: As i understand mysql don't support indexing of json columns?

Comment: Not directly,  but as in @Bipil Raut answer on the above link, they can be virtualized via [Secondary Indexes and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html)

Comment: Hi is it possible to create multi-valued index on array of strings. I tried something like: CREATE INDEX products ON components ( (CAST(data->'$.products' AS VARCHAR(255) ARRAY)) ) but it gives me error. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have never had a use case myself where I've needed to create a secondary index,  so I would not be able to help you there. My suggestion is to post a new question with your details above.