# Creating an index on a json column with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mysql-8.0

I have a db table with a `JSON` column. I now want to add an index to parts of that json.

It turns out you can only add an index on a json column [when creating the table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532057/10924593).

Here's what I tried in a migration:

```php
DB::statement(DB::raw(<<<SQL
CREATE TABLE area_groups (
  title JSON, 
  `created_at` timestamp null, 
  `updated_at` timestamp null, 
  INDEX area_groups_title_de (
    (
      JSON_VALUE(title, '$.de')
    )
  ), 
  INDEX area_groups_title_en (
    (
      JSON_VALUE(title, '$.en')
    )
  )
) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
SQL
));

Schema::table('area_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id()->change();
    $table->foreignId('area_id')->change()->constrained();
});
```

My idea was to create the json column and indexes in a raw db statement and do the rest with Laravel's migration helpers.

Creating the table seems to work, but running this migration fails with the following error message:

```
Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Index::_addColumn() must be of the type string, null given, called in vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Schema/Index.php on line 72
```

Comment: Where exactly does it say that this works only when creating a table?

Comment: @Alex Doing something like `create index area_groups_title_de on area_groups(JSON_VALUE(title, '$.de'));` gives me a mysql syntax error.

Comment: And the mysql docs on json indexes only mention create table

Comment: Are you sure you're using a mysql version that supports what you're trying to do? Also, I don't think you need DB::raw inside DB::statement.

Comment: @IGP yes, when I run that `create table` statement manually on a console it works.

Comment: What about not using `DB::raw`? (`DB::statement(<<<SQL ... SQL);`)

Answer (score -2):

you can use `json_encode(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'User 1']);`

**[Laravel Schema](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns)** does support JSON field types as well.

You can use text field type as well to store JSON data.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to add a mysql index to a column in my json column, not for a way to encode json.